# Why Date from "react-datepicker" is getting registered as the "previous date" in ISOFormat? Is this due to location from where date is being posted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I am building a social-networking type application using react, typescript and RHF (react-hook-forms as the forms handling library),
I have created a reusable input component for handling dates named : `"AppDateInput.tsx"` using react-hook-form

Below is my reusable file for dates (AppDateInput.tsx - component)

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { FieldValues, UseControllerProps, useController } from "react-hook-form";
import Datepicker from "react-datepicker";
 
// @mui/material
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import FormHelperText from "@mui/material/FormHelperText";
 
interface Props extends UseControllerProps<FieldValues, any> {};
 
export default function AppDateInput (props : Props) {
 
// react-hook-form
const {field, fieldState} = useController({...props, defaultValue : new Date()});
 
const today = new Date();
 
return (
 <Fragment>
  <FormControl fullWidth = {true}>
    <Datepicker
     {...props}
     {...field}
     dateFormat = {'dd/MM/yyyy'}
     selected = {field.value && new Date(field.value) || null}
     onChange = {(date) => field.onChange(date)} 
     minDate = {today}
     todayButton = {'Today'}/>
     
    <FormHelperText sx = {{mx : 0}} error = {!!(fieldState.error)}>
      {fieldState.error?.message}
    </FormHelperText>
  </FormControl>
 </Fragment>
)}
```

**the date is getting registered into the console (going to API Server as well),** when I **fire the submit event**, and everything went correctly. The date being shown into the input-field-box of the datepicker is into the format: `"dd/MM/yyyy"` *(normal date format by react-datepicker)*,  but the value being stored into the `date : Date | null` property inside of my **Activity.ts (a modal containing a social-networking activity)** is of ISOString format  of the previous date (right before the one being selected), although it being is ISOString is ok and needed too.

For eg, If I selected today's date: (23/08/2023), then into the `'date'` property it is getting stored as `"2023-08-22T18:00:00.000Z"` (as you can see here, the date is previous day's date), and not the one being selected , i.e. `"23-August-2023"`. I want to know why this behaviour is arising, it is really getting onto my nerve and I know you would be this would be the best place for resolving this little query of mine. why this is happening? and do provide me solution to this problem of mine

below is my `asyncthunk` for creating a new activity:

```
 export const createActivityAsync = createAsyncThunk<Activity, Activity>(
    'activity/createActivityAsync',
    async (activity, thunkAPI) => {
    const {username, joinDate, resignDate} = activity;
    try { return await agent.UserExperiences.create(username, activity); }
    catch (error : any) { return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({error : error.data}); }});
```

handling the responses as : (inside extraReducers of my **activitySlice.ts** as : -

```
    // 1.a) create new activity- (when pending)
       builder.addCase(createActivityAsync.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'pending';
       });
    
       // 1.b) create new activity - (when fulfilled)
       builder.addCase(createActivityAsync.fulfilled, (state, action : 
 PayloadAction<Activity>) => {
        state.activity = action.payload;
        state.status = 'idle';
       });
    
       // 1.c) create new activity - (when rejected)
       builder.addCase(createActivityAsync.rejected, (state) => {
        state.status = 'idle';
       });
```

I am from India. Is this because of the Indian Subcontinental timezone, the ISOString is registering the previous date into the API Server?

Is this really a timezone mismatch issue only? Or, I am making a big mistake during handling dates using AppDateInput.tsx?

If that's a case, then how could I resolve this (timezone, if it is!) issue, could you suggest me any changes (small or big) to do inside of my *AppDateInput.tsx* file?

I have also created a native function for converting the ISOString dates into the javascript date object and to render as string here

**DateUtility function (just an add-on)**

```
const ISODateNormalizer = (ISOdate : Date, length : string) : string => {
const date = new Date(ISOdate);
 
const {days, months} = {
 days : ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
 months : ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];                  
};
 
const normalizedDate = `${days[date.getUTCDay()]}
                        ${months[date.getUTCMonth()]}
                        ${date.getUTCDate()}
                        ${date.getUTCFullYear()}`;
switch (length) {
 case 'concise' : return `${months[date.getUTCMonth()]}, ${date.getUTCFullYear()}`;
 case 'extended' : return normalizedDate;
 default : return normalizedDate;
}};
```

Please provide the solution to this problem of mine,

Do I have to let the date be in javascript date object format when being submitted inside of the reusable - `AppDateInput.tsx` component, and then de-structure it inside of the `createAsyncThunk ()` - method for creating the activity, and then convert it into the ISOString of that particular javascript date, and then inject it back to the request body? and send to API Server?

if this is one solution then please help me in achieving this by providing your inputs, and if you have any another solution, please provide me that solution as well...

**Thank you so much in advance :)**